# ModuleNotFoundError in heroku

Tags: python, django

The following is the part of log i retrieved.

```
2020-06-13T12:45:56.559432+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-06-13T12:45:56.559432+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-13T12:45:56.559433+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'berncodes_project.wsgi'
2020-06-13T12:45:56.559522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-13 12:45:56 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-13T12:45:56.584694+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-13 12:45:56 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592976+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-13 12:45:56 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592978+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592979+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592980+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592980+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592981+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592981+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592982+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592983+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592983+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592984+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592984+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592985+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592985+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592990+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592991+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592991+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592992+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592992+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-13T12:45:56.592992+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'berncodes_project.wsgi'
2020-06-13T12:45:56.593132+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-13 12:45:56 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-06-13T12:45:56.628458+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-13T12:45:56.628466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
2020-06-13T12:45:56.628847+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
2020-06-13T12:45:56.628848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 545, in manage_workers
```

I did everything right. I think its an issue with the django project name. Is there any configuration i need to adjust for it to run?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error
In the requirements.txt file add all the modules that you have accessed externaly

Comment: the suggestion you are giving is hard to do, some modules may have their own dependencies and so on, i.e why `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is used